# I want to save correct date and time in database using php. If my system date is wrong then it saves wrong date

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use following coding to save a date in database. Please help me to save correct date and time:

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: You would have to get the time from external source like a server in your time zone, or a server that is capable of returning time for particular time zone.

Comment: what would you understand by "correct date and time"??? normally the date and time is stored in this format, but information regarding the time zone would be useful. Moreover, saving all the date and time in GMT+0 would be a good idea, or saving information of the time zone associated with the date.

Comment: i am new in php. please help me to use time zone

Answer (score 0):

I think your are facing problem for not set default time zone.

Set your time zone

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo'); ?>
```

Here the list of time zone

[Time zone list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Now If you try your code now,you will get correct date time.

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo $mysqldate;
```

Comment: Did you used your time zone ? See the list that I have provided.

Comment: Please write your full code, that you have tried or just let me see your time zone function code.

Comment: <?php  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');    $mysqldate = date(Y-m-d H:i:s');     echo $mysqldate    ?>

Comment: Please write the output, what's the output ? Is it like this 2015-10-08 17:06:43 ?

Comment: Output : 2015-10-06 17:08:47

Comment: Your pc datetime is not correct.Change your pc datetime.

Comment: I dont want system date and time.  I want actual date and time. if in some case my system date is wrong then it saves wrong date. i want to save correct date and time. i change my system date 6 oct. and it shows 6 oct. but i want date should be 8 oct(correct date).

Comment: From where php will pickup your date ?See the XAMlMAX comment.

Comment: Do you know why you have install Xampp or Wamp ? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting

Comment: Yes. It is local server.

Comment: So, Now you agree to it's taking datetime from server ? Local server isn't a server ?

Comment: You asking me a question. i want answer. I already told that i am new in php. i want help.